# jQuery Mobile Back Button not going back (and not responsive without href)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, pushstate

I have the following header:

```
<div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back" data-position="fixed">
    <h3>Title</h3>

    <a data-role="button" data-transition="fade" data-theme="c" data-rel="back" href="" data-direction="reverse"
        data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left"
    > Back </a>

    <a data-role="button" data-transition="fade" data-theme="c"
        href="#page2" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right"
        class="ui-btn-right ui-disabled"
    > Next </a>
</div>
```

The back button doesn't go back. If I set it to `""` or `"#"`, it redirects to my home page. If I don't have the `href` attribute, clicking the button does nothing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, revert to the basics.

```
    events : {
        "click .back" : "back"
    },

    back : function() {
        window.history.back();
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

You are operating within the context of a `data-role="header"` element, so adding `data-add-back-btn="true"` should be sufficient for adding a back button.

My guess would be that jQM is not expecting to see another back button with the header - and therefore is not enhancing it properly. Try removing `data-add-back-btn="true"` or your custom back button, having both may be the issue.

Under normal circumstances, setting an `href` is not required and you should be able to get away with setting it to '#'. As long as you have `data-rel="back"`, jQM should take care of the functionality for you.

Comment: What version of jQM are you using? `data-add-back-btn="true"` only works on `data-role="page"` as of v1.0.1. It will also only appear when you navigate to the page from another (i.e. when there's something to transition back to). As for your standard button, without an href, it will act as if your are clicking 'back' in your browser window. If there's no history available, the button won't do anything.

Comment: Ah, so I don't want to use `data-add-back-btn` because of my current setup (dynamically appending pages to the body using Backbone). I'm using version 1.2.0. I also tried `$(page.el).attr('data-add-back-btn', 'true');` on the `data-role="page"`. It properly created the back button, but for some reason it always goes back to my home page (`/`). I'm so confused!